# Can I use (てform verb) repeatedly with different verbs to emphasize different actions, or is it just with one verb?

Tags: grammar

If not, is there a structure that will grammatically allow for that? Like "I eat right, exercise, stay consistent about it, and yet I've lost no weight in weeks!"

Comment: Are you familiar with the ～たり... して method of listing items?

Comment: A refresher on its function would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There are two questions here: (1) can you use the て-form several times and (2) is this what you need in your example?

Comment: In particular, something like when someone says "勉強しても、勉強しても、勉強してもこれを分からない" to emphasize they can't understand something no matter how much they study, if something similar can be done with more than one verb in a sentence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can use ～ても～ても for this:

> ダイエットしても、運動しても、食べ過ぎなくても、全然[痩]{や}せない！
>   Even though I've dieted, exercised, and kept myself from overeating, I still can't lose weight!

You can also use ～たり～たりする, but the meaning is slightly different:

> ダイエットしたり、運動したりしても、全然[痩]{や}せない！
>   Even though I've done all kinds of things like dieting and exercise, I still can't lose weight!

The core difference between these 2 options is that ～ても～ても is usually an exhaustive list of things you've tried (or is intended to resemble an exhaustive list), ～たり～たりする is intended to refer to examples of things you've done and is not intended to be taken as exhaustive.  As a result, IMO, ～ても～ても comes off more whiney than ～たり～たり; the connotation with the first one being "I've tried everything!", the second being "I've tried a bunch of things".

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to emphasize the repetition of the actions of eating right and then exercising as maybe say in a regime, you could use the V1てはV2 pattern, which [大辞林](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF) describes as:

> ④ 繰り返される動作・作用について、前件と後件とを結ぶ。 「寄せ－返す浜の白波」 「ころんでは起き、ころんでは起きて…」

I'm going to assume you mean by eating right to mean mostly the amount as opposed to having a healthy (健康) well balanced diet. So then you could say

> 適度な食事をしては運動する。けれども全然痩せない。

You can repeat it to even further emphasize the repetition:

> 適度な食事をしては運動し、また適度な食事をしては運動する。けれども全然痩せない。

In more casual language though, you might instead say

> 適度な食事と運動をしているのに、全然痩せないんだ。